# Can Numba modify Dataframe values without return and reassignment?

Tags: pandas, group-by, numba

Given a DataFrame `df` with a top-level index "Name" and numerical columns ["X", "Y"]:

We are passing the DataFrame column values, grouped by "Name", into a Numba function `modify_Col_Y` like this:

```
@numba.njit
def modify_Col_Y(x: npt.NDArray[np.float64], y: npt.NDArray[np.float64]) -> npt.NDArray[np.float64]:
    n = len(x)
    for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
        y[i-1] = x[i]+y[i]
    return y

df.groupby('Name', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: modify_Col_Y(x['X'].to_numpy(), x['Y'].to_numpy()))
```

Is it possible for the Numba function `modify_Col_Y` to alter the values in DataFrame Column "Y" without returning and assigning them back to the DataFrame?

Presently, in order to get the modified Column "Y" values back into the DataFrame we have to interject a "`sendReceiveGroup`" function like this:

```
def sendReceiveGroup(g):
    g['Y'] = modify_Col_Y(g['X'].to_numpy(), g['Y'].to_numpy())
    return g

df.groupby('Name', group_keys=False).apply(sendReceiveGroup)
```

Aside from the extra functional layer, it appears likely that this approach makes an extra copy of the column values.  We're wondering if this can be avoided?

Here is a simple DataFrame to use for this example:

```
j = [(a, b) for a in ['A','B','C','D','E'] for b in pd.date_range('2020-01-01','2020-01-05').tolist()]
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(j, names=['Name','Date'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(25), i, columns=['X'])
df['Y'] = np.round(df['X'])
```